# How to reduce docker output in CI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

When running Docker in CI we get lots and lots (and lots) of lines like

`abc123 Extracting [=================================================> ]  237.3MB/239.3MB`

is it possible to pass a switch or something to Docker to signal we run in CI and would like to output non-interactive output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to `docker pull` or `docker build` commands. If so, you have the `--quiet` (or `-q`) flag:

```bash
docker pull --quiet ubuntu

docker build --quiet . -t 'something'
```

Comment: yes, `docker build`. I'll try adding `--quiet`